# Django Query - How can do Prefetch filter with values based on root query?

Tags: django, orm, django-queryset, django-orm, django-filter

For better performance, i use prefetch selected to get all in one single query like this:

```
profile = Profile.objects.only('id','series_following').prefetch_related(
        Prefetch('books_reading', queryset=Book.objects.only('id').filter(
                series_id=`series_following_id`), to_attr='books')).get(user=request.user_id)
```

I want to get all books are reading with series_following, but i dont know how to put it to filter.
Here are my models:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    series_following = models.ForeignKey('Series')
    books_reading = models.ManyToManyField('Book', related_name="readers_reading_book",         
        null=True, blank=True)
    ...

class Series(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    ...

class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    series = models.ForeignKey(Series)
    ...
```

Comment: You say you want to get all books, but `series_following` deals with `Series`?

Comment: Yeh, what i asking here is there a way to take series_following from root query and put it to filter in prefetch.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure your models are wired as you might expect them to be, but how about something like this?

```py
user = request.user

books = Book.objects.filter(
    series = user.profile.series_following
)
```

That will get you all the books that a have the same series as the one a user is following based on their profile.

Comment: oh of course but i just want 1 query to get all -.-

Comment: Maybe explain what you are trying to do with your code? You have access to the `user`, the `user.profile`, and the filtered `books` all in your view.

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain the `Book`s with:

```
Book.objects.filter(
    series__readers_reading_book__user=request.user
)
```

Comment: but i want my profile too with books, just 1 query is possible ?

Comment: @ClasYusa: a `Prefetch` will not be done in the same query: a `Prefetch` is a promise to make one extra query.